# How to align text in center

Tags: css

I want global navigation bar to align center. #nav in `.gnb` class. parent element `#nav` width is 1173px. So I set up width left and right element each 107px, 163px. naturally `.gnb` class get the rest value that is 903px. but `.gnb` class does not working. why does this happen?

```css
/* no reset.css */

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

#header{
    position: relative;
    width: 1173px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .left li a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#555;
} 

#header .left li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 46px;
}

/* 첫 번째 자식 구분선 해제 */

#header .left li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}

#header .left li:first-child:after{
    display: none;
}

/* 로고 구분선 */

#header .left li:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

/* 왼쪽 로고 이미지 */

#header .left li:first-child a{
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_sky_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#header .left li:nth-child(2) a{
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_aqua_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#header .left li:last-child a{
    padding: 0 0 0 33px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_water_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

/* 오른쪽 */

.family,
.members,
.lang{
    display: inline-block;
}
#header .right{
    float: right;
}

#header .right li,
a{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 46px;
}

#header .family > a:last-child{
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#header .family a:hover{
    color: #590fe4;
}

#header .members a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

#header .members a,
#header .lang a{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#header .family a,
#header .members a{
    padding: 0 11px;
}

#header .family a,
#header .members a,
#header .lang a{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555;
}

#header .family li:first-child:after,
#header .members li:first-child:after{
    display: none;
}

#header .family li:after,
#header .members li:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

#header .lang a{
    padding-right: 16px;
    height: 46px; 
    background: url('img/lang_arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
}

/* 네비게이션 */

nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

#nav{
    width: 1173px;
    height: 99px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav h1{
    width: 107px;
    float: left;
    height: 99px;
    background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
}

#nav h1 > a{
    color: transparent
}

#nav .gnb{
    width: 903px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav .info{
    width: 163px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>롯데월드 어드벤처</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#">SEOUL SKY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">롯데월드 아쿠아리움</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">김해롯데워터파크</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
                <div class="family">
                    <li><a href="#">민속박물관</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">아이스링크</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="members">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">회원가입</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="lang">
                    <a href="#">KOR</a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="nav">
            <h1><a href="#">롯데월드 어드벤처</a></h1>
            <ul class="gnb">
                <li><a href="#">즐길거리</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">요금/우대혜택</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">참여프로그램</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">이용가이드</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">소통서비스</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="info">
                <li><a href="#">검색</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">예매</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">단체</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add an image maybe of what is desired output? That'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want to by the word "not working"
But found typo on stylesheet:

```css
#header .right li,
a{
```

comma is not need for that line.
If you are looking for another problem, explain it more :)